# Asp Textbox vs input type text performance in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, performance

**asp:TextBox** is a server side control which will be rendered every time the page is loaded. Is it a good option to use plain HTML **input type="text"** tag if I really don't need any server side processing on the textbox or will it make no difference in the performance?

Comment: Did you benchmark your entire application and find out that a single `asp:TextBox` is grinding your application to a halt? Or asking because just curious? Yes, there will be an overhead, but it will be negligible.

Comment: I didn't. I was thinking of making it as a habit(if that is a good one) use to plain HTML tags if server side processing was not required.

Answer (score 1):

Actually what you are seing is exactly one of the advantages of using Server Controls.

I say ServerControls because there are two types of Server Controls:

1. Html Server controls
2. Web Controls.

The first one are designed to help when migrating existing applications and the second one offer a much richer experience, including a more standardized set of properties, events, and other goodies.

To answer your question, try the following code enter some text in the three textboxes and notice how both that have the runat=server attribute will persist their values, not only that you can use them in server-side code without using the "ugly" Request collections (QueryString, Form, etc) in a strongly typed manner.

Again, what is happening is that the Page and Controls Framework is saving their values in a hidden media called ViewState where it will "persist" their values back, and help raising events (like TextChanged) in the server.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know that asp controls provide more rich experience and easier programming, but there may be cases when I need to process the textbox entirely on the client side and viewstate may not be required at all.